# Geodata Querying Optimisations

Tags: geolocation, quadtree, spatial-index, geohashing, location-based-service

I am planning to write a Node.js-powered RESTful web service that I will use for a mobile application which provides some sort of location based features. The most basic use case is going to look something like this:

- the user can create a resource by sending a request to the web service containing the resource's name and the user's current location (latitude and longitude)
- the web service will store the metadata about this resource internally in some sort of collection
- the user can query the web service for a list of resources within 5km of his current location

One of the first problems that came up in my mind was scalability. Let's suppose that at some point in the future the server will hold metadata for 1 million resources. When a user will query for nearby results, looping through 1 million entries to compute the distance will take forever.

There are many services out there that have the same flow, so I thought implementing something like this is not going to take me a lot of time.  I might have been wrong.

I am now two days into researching proven methods and algorithms. By now I have read everything I could put my hands on about QuadTrees, Geohases, databases with spatial indexing support, formulas and so on. However, I still can't get the whole picture of how everything is going to work.

I was hoping that maybe someone who has worked on something similar could share his insight on what approach might be the most suitable considering this use case and the technologies that I am planning to use.  Also, a short description of how it can be implemented would help me a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For those who are also looking for more information on this topic out of  curiosity, my answer might not provide much clearance. However, some answers in [here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/18330/would-it-be-possible-to-use-geohash-for-proximity-searches) might help you understand how you could achieve proximity searches using Geohashes.

My approach, after doing a little research on [Redis](http://redis.io/), will be not to overcomplicate things and just use the tools that are already out there. It has out of the box support for spatial indexing and will most probably meet all my persistance requirements for this project.

Apparently [MongoDB](https://www.mongodb.org/) also comes with built-in support for geodata. In fact, even RDBMS like MySQL or SQLite do come with such capabilities.